# How do you group posts on a users timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

We have an app that posts ever few days. I can see some apps it auto groups these posts on the timeline.  With our app it just shows as a new post and does not group them.

How can we get them to group?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an open graph action for your app. Have a look at this to get started
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/